# Start MS Word inside my own window

Tags: c#, automation, ms-office

I execute MS Word with IDispatch->Invoke, but I need Word's text editor field  (or the whole Word's window) to be appeared inside my own window. Is it possible?

Comment: No, this is not possible. You can use vba to do some neat tricks but this requires the user to enable developer tools. I'd suggest starting there.

Comment: But it looks like Edraw does something like I need https://www.edrawsoft.com/images/screenshots/infographic.png ? Looks like embedded MS Office window inside their own window.

Comment: Yeah... that looks like EDraw has implemented an impressively Microsoftonian GUI. I like it a lot, but yeah, it would be a ton of work. It sounds like it's time to think about what you're trying to do and figure out a way to implement the functionality you need, write a Word plugin, or figure out how to lean on VBA for support.